# Correct way to use async class based views in Django

Tags: django, async-await, python-asyncio

I am trying to use the very new `Django 3.1` Async view classes. 
Based on the limited documentation available, I have tried to create my own `async def __call__()` method. 
From the documents:

> For a class-based view, this means making its `__call__()` method an `async def` (not its `__init__()` or `as_view()`).

[Django 3.1 Development Documents](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/async/#async-views)

However, until now I have had no luck with writing an asynchronous class based view. I constantly get `await` exceptions, or `asyncio.iscoroutinefunction` returns `False`, which I assume should return true if the class is actually Asynchronous.

Since the documentation is lacking an example, could someone with more knowledge of async programming help me with an example of a class based asynchronous view?

Comment: Could you post a code example of what you've tried?

Comment: https://medium.com/@bruno.fosados/django-async-class-based-views-acbv-5986c4511ae6

Comment: Is there any example where I can see async `__call__()` method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spend quite some time searching in the Django ticket system, blogposts (thx to Joren), etc. so you don't have to.

The best you can do is using the code from [the blog](https://medium.com/@bruno.fosados/django-async-class-based-views-acbv-5986c4511ae6):

```
class YourView(View):    
    @classonlymethod
    def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
        view = super().as_view(**initkwargs)
        view._is_coroutine = asyncio.coroutines._is_coroutine
        return view

    async def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

But you also need to be aware there is no way you can use actual generics (no async ORM support, even TemplateView doesn't work) and build-in [decorators](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32077#no1) for 3.1. You need to write your own stuff for things that Django normally does itself.

Comment: When I called the API with a different method (say PUT/POST) instead of raising **405 Method Not Allowed**, It responded with **500 - TypeError: object HttpResponseNotAllowed can't be used in 'await' expression**

I'm not sure how to fix this. Can you please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I get **You cannot call this from an async context - use a thread or sync_to_async.**

Answer (score 1):

```
class Test(CreateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    form_class = TestForm
    view_is_async = True # on async
```