# Django feeding file data to a model

Tags: python, django

If you got a form that asks the user for a file upload and the file after some preprocessing gets a data dict which is fed to the model.  How is the preprocessing step is to be done in this case? In the subclassed FormView's `is_valid` method one can do `form.files` to get the file obj, read it , preprocess it there and then feed the data to a model instance. But I think this would block the thread. What's the correct way?

Comment: I've used Celery for this to hand off to another process so as to not hold up the html render back to user, but I'm hoping someone answers with how to do this in the new async views.

Comment: You could use a celery task to do asynchronized processing if the processing is going to take too much time. https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Django 3.1 onwards you could do something like this

```
import asyncio
from django.http import JsonResponse
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async


@sync_to_async
def crunching_stuff(my_file):
    # do your file processing here
        
async def index(request):
    json_payload = {
        "message": "Your file is being processed"
    }
    my_file = request.POST.get('file')
    
    asyncio.create_task(crunching_stuff(my_file))
    return JsonResponse(json_payload)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But in the case of a class based view what would be async -ed? Which function should I add the `async`  keyword to?

Comment: ok I got an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62038200/correct-way-to-use-async-class-based-views-in-django

Comment: Another thing I just realised is that there are 2 blocking phases, 1 is when file is being uploaded and another is when file is being preprocessed. What should be made async in order for the file upload to be async?

Comment: You could use websockets or ajax on the front end