# async django CBV methods post in class CreateVIew

Tags: django, python-asyncio

I am need help in using async to python django in base class view.

```
class IndexPage(CreateView):
    """Page index site"""

    async def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs) -> object:
                await send_code(data['email'])
                return render(request, 'activate.html')
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

If you create this function simply as a function without a class, everything works fine, but an error occurs when using the class:

IndexPAge HTTP handlers must either be all sync or all async.

Please help anyone who has encountered this problem, thank you.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62038200/correct-way-to-use-async-class-based-views-in-django). The solution is to override the `View.as_view` and add `view._is_coroutine = asyncio.coroutines._is_coroutine` to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct way to use async class based views in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62038200/correct-way-to-use-async-class-based-views-in-django)

Comment: these methods only work for the VIew class

Comment: Yeah, but `CreateView` is subclass of `View`, right?

Comment: class CreateView(SingleObjectTemplateResponseMixin, BaseCreateView) -> class BaseCreateView(ModelFormMixin, ProcessFormView): -> class ProcessFormView(View):
Yes View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Test(CreateView):
template_name = 'index.html'
form_class = TestForm
view_is_async = True # on async
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for your code.